# Why isn't my POST Webhook working in Django?

Tags: python, django, webhooks

I use the app Salesmate and am trying to write a a client on my site that adds features through the API. For this to work I need Salesmate's Webhooks. My client is in Django.

When I send a GET request webhook it makes it into my client.

When I send a POST request webhook it never makes it into the view.

When I send a test POST request from https://reqbin.com/ it makes it into the view and performs as expected.

I've played endlessly with the JSON body and headers. There could still be something I'm missing here, or there could be a flag raised in Django invalidating the sender, or something else...

Here is Salesmate webhook request, in the app. I've played with many headers, and sent requests with and without JSON bodies.
[deleted for privacy]

Here is my django view. Super simple, but it never gets called.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse


@csrf_exempt
def pab(request):

    #Do something simple and trackable

    return HttpResponse(keep)
```

Comment: did you add the view path to project urls? see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path

Comment: I did. What is funny is that this view works when I send a GET from the app, or even a POST from a third party. Also I can receive a POST from the app by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Django module "Moderna" which was causing some issues, still not sure what. I started a naked django app and it started working.